# how to initialize hashmap on class level without using static block

Tags: java, spring, hashmap

I want to initialize one Hashmap, but I don't want to use Constructor way, neither do I want to initialize it in static block. Can you please tell me how to do that?

```
public ClassName() {
    idToSkillREs = new HashMap();
}
```

I don't want to use in these way

Comment: did you try to initialize it outside the block/constructor and get an error?

Comment: How can you initialize anything without constructor?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg he means outside the constructor of the ClassName, not without the Hashmap's constructor. It got me confused, too. Still, you can always initialize it as null

Comment: @vefthym after reviewing the answers, I've already got the point, but still OP should formulate his requirements more straight.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg definitely!

Comment: Static block is `static{..}` and it doesn't have much in common with constructor since it is responsible for class initialization while constructor handles instance initialization. Maybe instead of static block `static{...}` you mean initialization block `{...}`?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply declare it as instance member on top and initialise it right away.

```
Map<Type,Type> idToSkillREs = new HashMap<Type,Type>();

public ClassName() {

}
```

That is not a constructor, neither a static block.

Answer (score 1):

What about an initialization (non static) block?

```
public class ClassName() {

    Map<Type, Type> idToSkillREs; // nothing here

    {
        idToSkillREs= new HashMap<Type,Type>(); // this will run before the constructor
    }

    public Classname() {
        // constructor code
    }
}
```

Comment: why use a block in the first place and not go for SURESH ATTA's suggestion?

Comment: @vefthym maybe, for ability to add some elements in the time of initialization without hacks with anonymous subclass (i.e `new HashMap<Type, Type> {{put(x, y);}}`).

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg you are right. That could be useful (even if I doubt that that's the case with the OP). Still, you can use a block after the initialization to add elements

Answer (score 1):

I think this qualifies.  We are creating a `Map` "on the class level", and initializing it by adding some entries (!!) ... all without a static initializer block.

```
public class Example {
    private static final Map<String, String> skillz =
         new HashMap<String><String>(){{
             put("knitting", "excellent");
             put("macrame", "passable");
             put("sword-fighting", "poor");
         }};
    ...
}
```